# CF: AWS::SES::ConfigurationSetEventDestination EventDestination to SNS Topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I was trying to create CF to configure SES->ConfigSet->Event-Destination to SNS->Topic, But I am surprised to see on AWS document as,

Note: You can't specify Amazon SNS event destinations in CloudFormation templates

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ses-configurationseteventdestination-eventdestination.html

But same can be achieved from AWS Console. From CF I can create empty SES->ConfigSet but I can't add any destination from CF,

What is the otherway to achieve this from CF template?

Thanks

Comment: Typically to overcome limitations of cfn, you create [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

Comment: Yea, but thinking if I can add 'aws cli' which supports the same need in my CF stack or anyway to call shell comand, Also this AWS resource has dependancy on other resource and vice versa. Howver when I delete the stack that needs to delete the this special AWS resource as well. Thanks.